# Javascript add class if parent has class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a second `class` to a `div` if one of the parents has a certain `class`
This is what I did:

```
var h = document.querySelectorAll('h1,h2,h3,h4,p'); //GET ALL ELEMENTS
for (var i = 0; i < h.length; i++) { // LOOP THROUGH IT AND ADD A CLASS
    if (h[i].classList.length === 0) {
        h[i].classList.add("fontFit");
    }
}

var image_large = document.getElementsByClassName('image_large');
var fontFit = document.getElementsByClassName('fontFit');

if ($(fontFit).parents().hasClass('image_large')){ //IF `fontFit` has a parent named `image_large`; execute the `for` loop.
    for (var j = 0; j < image_large.length; j++) {
        if (fontFit[j].classList.length === 1) {
            fontFit[j].classList.add('addClass');
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't throw me an error but I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the HTML.

Comment: Why are you using `image_large.length` in your for loop condition when you are iterating over `fontFit`

Comment: @PatrickEvans. Good point. Changed it to `fontfit`. Now every element that has the `fontFit`-class also has a `addClass`-class

Comment: Because your only check is `fontFit[j].classList.length === 1`

Comment: What do you say? Move the `parent check` to the if statement?

Comment: just do `$('.image_large .fontFit').addClass('classname')` that will tell jQuery to find all elements that have a class named `fontFit` that are children of an element with class `image_large`

Comment: HOLY SH*T... this simple... Thank you. As you can see my `js` isn't my strong suit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is suffering from a logic error. Your code seems to assume that by doing the if statement first that all elements in `fontFit` are going to have a parent with a class `image_large`. But that is not true, some might some might not, you would rather test inside the loop

```
for (var j = 0; j < fontFit.length; j++) {
  //note uses Element#closest, a more recently added DOM method
  //if no parent with that class is found null is returned
  if( fontFit[j].closest('.image_large') ){
    fontFit[j].classList.add('addClass');
  }
}
```

Of course you could just as easily directly find all elements with class `fontFit` that are children of `image_large` by using the right selector and then just looping over that collection

```
var fontFit = document.querySelector('.image_large .fontFit');
fontFit.forEach(element=>element.classList.add('addClass'));
//Or in jQuery since you seem to have it
$('.image_large .fontFit').addClass('addClass');
```